# gettext() intelesence is not available in selenium

Tags: selenium, web, driver

I have been trying to get the text for the pop up window using the gettext() method, i am unable to get even the gettext() method in the intelesence in the selenium webdriver.

Comment: Well what would you like `getText` to do with a popup? What do you intend to get?

Comment: Help on how to navigate to a pop up window on clicking a button and then how to find the text of any of the element inside the pop up...thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get anything from a pop up window you have to switch the driver over to the new window:

```
driver.switchTo().window("WindowName");
```

You can get the window handles (selenium specific) by calling:

```
driver.getWindowHandles();
```

this returns a set of string handles which you can then pass to the `switchTo().window()` method.  Once you are in the desired window you can get the element's text.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
driver.switchTo().window("WindowName");    
String strText = driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getText();
```

Enjoy!